How to Open IntelliJ IDEA from Command Line with Current Folder
In VSCode, I can simply type code . to open the current folder as a project. I want to achieve a similar behavior with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition on Windows.
I have tried to configure command-line launcher by adding %Path% variables. While I was able to use 'idea.bat' or 'idea64.exe' to open IntelliJ, it always opens the default project.

As described on this page, the command is :
idea64.exe C:\MyProject

And you can use the %cd% variable to open the current folder.
idea64.exe %cd%


or you can just do idea64.exe .
